# How to bind a "progress" and update event to an ajax request when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I m uploading files to server with FormData api and ajax in php-codeigniter. My upload just works fine on file select event..But I want to show a progress bar beside every file that is being uploaded with the updated percentage. My ajax is:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?=site_url('admin/commoncontroller/upload')?>",
    type : "POST",
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary");
    },
    processData : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    data : fd                
}).done(function(res){
    alert (res);
})
```

And I have found two ajax event viz AjaxSend and Complete to put the progress event in but I dont know how would I bind a progress(or any) event to a $.ajax() call. I already used the ajaxSend and Complete like:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $(".easyPieChart").show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $(".easyPieChart").hide();
});
```

But those events just show a progress bar(it's a canvas) on start end dissappear on complete.. not update in percentage. Any ideas how to do it.. thanks.

Comment: You can use the code @ http://jsfiddle.net/5ZRfY/ to make the progress bar

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/

Comment: @Akshat Thanx for early feed back I m on it..

Comment: @samitha Thank u. I will be checking on it..

Comment: @Akshat Sorry bro..It's just a progrss bar animation.. The main requirement of mine is to show the real updated percentage from server which is I think possible by means of an ongoing/running ajx request event. I think I m getting it but just dont know how to add the listener to the $.ajax.. Thanx anyway.

Comment: @samitha Sorry..I can't take this. It's huge. And I'm on codeigniter..so It would have nice if some ajax event related solution could be found. This link [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) shows with raw XMLHtpRequest object but it's vague to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do this..

```
    $.ajax({ //all prviuos codes and the new things to add as follows:
            ....
            ....

      xhrFields : { 
                  onprogress: function (e) {
                     if (e.lengthComputable){
                     var percentage= Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                     $("#percentage").prop('data-percent',percentage);
                     $(".percent").text(percentage);
                     canvas.update(percentage);}
                   },

                  onload  : function(e){
                    if (e.lengthComputable){
                                canvas.update(100);
                    }
                    }
                 },
           //Other ajax context here..

        });
```

Thats it my progress is being shown now... :)